# Is an activity a class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Sorry for the noob question - still learning.

When building android apps in Android studio, every new activity has it's own XML and java class.  I'm trying to get an understanding of the overall architecture - When creating a new activity how is this stacked in the package as a whole?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/intro-activities

Comment: And https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Comment: you likely are missing Android basics. Take time to pass through some lessons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your activities are indeed classes. Look at the declarations!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
       ^^^^^
//  see? it's a class!
```

And the class is in whatever package it says on the top of the file. e.g.

```
package com.example.myapp;
```

> every new activity has it's own XML

I guess this is where you are most confused. The XML file is just a resource file. It's just a description of the components in an activity. XML files like that are usually located in something like the `app/src/main/res/layout/` folder. They are not classes.

So how are the XML file and your `Activity` subclass linked together. The answer lies here:

```
setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);
```

Go to your `Activity` subclass's `onCreate` method, you will find a line like the above. `R.layout.activity_main` refers to the XML file. This line is when your activity class reads the XML file and loads the views contained in that file and set it as the content view. The `R` class here is automatically generated by Android Studio and it contains references to your resources.